# In an Azure Functions binding, is there any way to query Cosmos DB for documents based on a date relative to today?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I've got an Azure Function with a Cosmos DB binding. What I want to do is to get all the documents with a date in the future.

Something like this would work...

```
SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Filter = {FilterTerm} AND c.SomeDate < '" + DateTime.UtcNow + "'")]
```

Except that the fact that the binding live in an attribute means they have to be a constant expression.

As far as I can tell, there aren't any functions built into Cosmos DB (like, for instance, [`GetDate()` in T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)).

So currently I'm querying the lot and doing the date filtering in memory. This works, but it means a lot more DB traffic than I'd like.

Is there any way to do this more effectively?

Comment: Hi,Tom.Not sure what you said that `the binding live in an attribute means they have to be a constant expression`. Per my understanding, you want to implement GetDate() function in cosmos db query sql, right? So that you could filter the data on the server side.

Comment: @JayGong I think we're talking about the same thing. Your answer looks promising - I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: Yeah,any updates,just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there aren't any functions like GetDate() built into Cosmos DB cosmos db, you could use [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#udf) to implement similar function.

udf:

```
function convertTime(unix_timestamp){

      var date = new Date();
      return date;
    //   var year = date.getFullYear();
    //   var month = ("0"+(date.getMonth()+1)).substr(-2);
    //   var day = ("0"+date.getDate()).substr(-2);
    //   var hour = ("0"+date.getHours()).substr(-2);
    //   var minutes = ("0"+date.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
    //   var seconds = ("0"+date.getSeconds()).substr(-2);

    //   return year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+hour+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
}
```

You could convert any format you want to match your field.

sql:

```
SELECT c.SomeDate < udf.nowDate() FROM c
```

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks Jay - I ended up just using ```function iso8601utcnow(){
    var d = new Date();
    return d.toISOString();
}```